# How can I setup my router with an IP-SEC VPN?

Tags: vpn

My basic problem is this: My Chromecast won't allow me to stream some content because of the country I live in. I'd like to, then, setup my router with a VPN.

I have a TP-Link model TD-W9970. In my admin page for the router I can only see an option to set up an IP-SEC VPN tunneling (which I don't really understand what is). I checked out several VPN services (such as ExpressVPN) but most of them use something called L2TP, which doesn't seem to be an option with my router. My question is:

1. Can I set my router? If so, how?
2. Is there any other option other than setting my router?
3. If I have to buy a new router that would allow this, what should I be looking for, specifically?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I think so. setting up a router with VPN is security, and also I couldn't find a better stack exchange website that looked more fitting. I'm not using VPN for anything else. I tried a few times some services for my PC and Android. How? It's rather simple really. Most services are very user-friendly and easy to use

Comment: @GeorgeBailey can you elaborate? Also, I'm trying to configure my router so *all* my devices go through a VPN. Will that not work? Why?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey using a service is easy. TunnelBear or VPNExpress make apps that streamlines all if it. I know how a VPN works in general, I never set one up myself and I don't think it's simple technologically. I just meant that if I want to unblock content on my PC it's easy to find a service. I want to unblock my Chromecast. I think routing all devices through VPN should do it but maybe not. I dont know.

Comment: *"I want to unblock my Chromecast."* I think you should focus your question on this. Since you are not using VPN at all right now. Setting up VPN to 'unblock' Chromecast sounds like overkill. Could you elaborate on why you decided a VPN is the best approach, and what problem you are trying to solve? (i.e. how do you know it is 'blocked' and by whom) I suspect there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @GeorgrBailey oh I see what's confusing you. There's no problem with my cast. I'm trying to watch content which is blocked in my country. I'd like Chromecast to think I'm from the US. I'm pretty sure VPN is the way to go

Comment: Connect Router to a VPN, connect Chromecast to Router, simplest solution to an easy problem.

Comment: Ramhound is correct. Please edit your question to no longer focus on the Chromecast so much, but rather on your router. You should clarify that you would like *all* devices to use the VPN. A short note explaining that you are "trying to watch content which is blocked in your country with a Chromecast" is a very helpful detail, but not the center of your question.

Comment: Also explain what you have tried on your router and how it has failed thus far.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not that easy turns out.

Comment: Why not? If you choose a VPN provider that supports IPSec, it is just a bunch of settings that you then need from the supplier. Just remember that, when the VPN is turned on, it is likely that ALL traffic goes through it.

Comment: @JulianKnight Most services offer L2TP and I couldn't find a decent tutorial or explanation about how to set up IP-SEC

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I edited my question to be more concise, though I don't think it wasn't very focused to begin with.

Comment: I'm adding an answer now

Comment: @JulianKnight just for reference, most guides look like [this](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-setup-purevpn-manually-on-tp-link-router) which is not helpful since I don't have the L2TP option, only IP-SEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with L2TP is that it is a layer 2 protocol that your router doesn't directly support. It will allow it through over IPSec but you would have to start it somewhere else which isn't what you want.

Most of the providers I've found so far provide VPN's that use protocols that can work over IPSec but operate at a higher layer and so need an application to start/terminate the VPN. PPTP and L2TP being the common protocols.

Your router, being one aimed at home users I think, and in common with many of the cheaper routers, doesn't fully support VPN's. It's support of IPSec allows it to be used as a tunnel but it cannot be the end-point.

So to do what you want, you need to either replace the router or set up a machine inside your network capable of terminating the VPN. Then use that machine as a router that you connect your devices to.

---

Replacing the router is likely the easiest option. You will need to look for a router that can terminate/originate either a PPTP and/or L2TP VPN connection. Not just act as a VPN passthrough.

My own preference is for the EdgeMax routers from Ubiquity Networks. I use the EdgeRouter Lite which can certainly be a VPN endpoint. The only thing to remember with the EdgeRouter's is that they don't include Wi-Fi. Ubiquity sell the Unifi range of access points. An EdgeRouter Lite and Unifi AP comes to about the same price as a decent SOHO WiFi router.

You could quote easily use your existing router to provide WiFi though if you wanted to (though you'd be very impressed by the power and stability of the Unifi).